# Is it possible to collect stories from an external RSS feed and display them on an internal site in SharePoint 2007?

Tags: sharepoint

Title says it all...basically I'd like to pull an external RSS feed and display their stories on an internal SharePoint site.

Is this possible? If so, can anybody provide direction?

If this is better suited for SuperUser let me know. I looked there and there aren't nearly as many SP questions there as there are here so I asked it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a step by step article:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/add-rss-feeds-to-your-sharepoint-site-HA010291095.aspx

Hope this is helpful for you.